# How to use Google Analytics API to create a custom dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to develop a custom SEO reporting system for clients. This system has a 'TRAFFIC DATA' module for which I'm planning to use Google analytics API for fetching data from an existing analytics account. Problem is that I'm literally clueless about where to find the API and how to use it in the system. I did some research about it and think something called 'EMBEDDED API' can be used for this.

Kindly help me with any resources, tutorials for this.
Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Aritro

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't know how to build a dashboard via PHP and APi, i dont recomend you do this in that way ... It's not so simple to build and you need knowledges of developing, HTTP resquest, etc.

Solutions

-> https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/  : The embed api is the simpliest way to do this. You only need to configure every Query and paste the HTML code on you Dash Boards

-> Use third party complements: You can use complements Like SuperMetrics or GeckoBoards, Clipfolio or other like these, this solution works well but you need to pay for theses services.  There a lot, just search for this on the net....

Now if you still want to do this via Api, i recomend you PHP (it's easy and cheap) and use the Rest API .
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

Visit the link for more information.

Remeber The steps are:

1 .- Create a Project in 
https://console.developers.google.com/

2.- Create the Autentification Protocol: 
If the data is from your account i recomend you use the Server to server solution ( in that case you need to configure p12 file)

3.- Build the query.